# combineReducer causes properties set to undefined

Tags: redux, reducers

Imagine I have the following simple reducer

```
let reducer = (prevState = {}, action) => {
    return {
        A: A(prevState.A, action),
        B: B(prevState.B, action)
    }
};
let A = B = (prevState, action) => {
    if (action.type == 'foo')
        return 'bar';
    else
        return prevState;
};
```

Any action, particularly @@INIT, will cause my state to become `{A: undefined, B: undefined}`. This is no ideal because my state is supposed to still be `{}` now

This is happening because I'm following the combineReducer pattern. Anyway to work around this?

Comment: reducers have to have some non-undefined initial state, otherwise you'll be getting: "Reducer "..." returned undefined during initialization. If the state passed to the reducer is undefined, you must explicitly return the initial state. The initial state may not be undefined.". So as you suggested in your comment somewhere, it would boil down to using something like null if you want to empty-like initial state.

Answer (score 1):

Your reducers are not supplying an initial state value for `prevState`.  So, the first time that `A()` or `B()` run, `prevState` is undefined, and returned.

The new ["Structuring Reducers"](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/StructuringReducers.html) section in the Redux docs covers this in the ["Initializing State"](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/InitializingState.html) guide.

Comment: Their initial value should be "missing", non-exist. Does it mean that I have to add assumptions like `A(prevState = null)` `B(prevState = -1)` everywhere? These properties are not supposed to have "initial value"

Comment: You don't _have_ to provide initial values.  But, unless you do _something_ different, right now you are definitely going to get `{A: undefined, B: undefined}`.